# Object with same type for all keys in Flow

Tags: javascript, dictionary, types, flowtype

I'm currently in the process of comparing the [Google Closure Compiler](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Annotating-JavaScript-for-the-Closure-Compiler) and the [Flow](https://flowtype.org/docs/) static type checker, in terms of expressiveness. One thing I know how to do in Closure but not in Flow is expressing a collection of named objects which all have the same type. In Closure one can use [the `@enum` annotation](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Annotating-JavaScript-for-the-Closure-Compiler#enum-type) for this.

```
/** @enum {function(number):number} */
const unaryFunctions = {
  sin: Math.sin,
  cos: Math.cos,
  square: function(x) { return x*x; },
};
```

Is there a way to do something like this using Flow? I guess I could use an ES6 dictionary instead of a plain object, but that would come at considerable overhead if cross-compiling to ES5. I think constructs like these seem pretty idiomatic, so I'm surprised I couldn't find a matching type description in the docs yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
const unaryFunctions: { ['sin'|'cos'|'square']: (number) => number } = {
  sin: Math.sin,
  cos: Math.cos,
  square: function(x) { return x*x; },
};
```

If you don't want to duplicate keys, you can rewrite it a bit:

```
const unaryFunctions_ = {
  sin: Math.sin,
  cos: Math.cos,
  square: function(x) { return x*x; },
};

const unaryFunctions: { [$Keys<typeof unaryFunctions_>]: (number) => number } = unaryFunctions_;
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you add some links to docs? I found [`$Keys`](https://flowtype.org/docs/utility-types.html#keyst) but haven't found a documentation for the way you use `[…]`. On the other hand I have found [indexer properties](https://flowtype.org/docs/syntax.html#object-types) which should allow `const unaryFunctions: {[name: string]: (number) => number} = {…}` if I understand it correctly. Doesn't limit to a finite set of keys, so it's not exactly an `@enum`, but I know of one other situation where I would be needing something like this. Or is your `[…]` an instance of this somehow?

Comment: https://flowtype.org/docs/objects.html#objects-as-maps You specify key type inside of the brackets. It can be string or anything more specific

Comment: In newer versions of Flow you can omit name in indexer, so instead of `{[name: string]: string}` you can simply write `{[string]: string}`

Comment: Now with the quotation marks added in, and the info about not naming the indexer, this makes a lot more sense. Thanks a lot!